# CakePHP blog tutorial - controller/view

Tags: cakephp, controller, naming-conventions

In CakePHP blog tutorial, http://book.cakephp.org/view/1536/Creating-Post-Views

there is a code for index.ctp

> Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
>   array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view',
>   $post['Post']['id'])); ?>

Why is it array('controller'=>'posts") ? aren't control names capitalized and it's called PostsController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the name of the controller as it would appear in the url.  Since this is an HTML link you would want the element to point to the correct url, in this case `pages/view/$id`.  If you said `PagesController/view/$id` it could very well be interpreted as needing the class `PagesControllerController`, this is probably unwanted behavior.